# Modals in Materializecss does not responding

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, materialize

I am trying to put a modal in MaterializeCss  but it does not trigger 
This is my code.

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>    

<div id="modal1" class="modal"><div class="modal-content">

<h4>Modal Header</h4>
<p>A bunch of text</p>
</div>
</div>  <script>$(document).ready(function(){$('.modal1').leanModal();
});</script>
```

Comment: Have you correctly imported Materialize css and JS files? It seems you're missing the JS files since I believe you're not receiving any console errors. If so, please show so I can better asses your problem.

Comment: Yes I have implemented <code>   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Materialize CSS docs](http://materializecss.com/modals.html), if you are using the latest version, you need to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```

see the difference? instead of `leanModal()` use `modal()`

also you are using `$('.modal1')` when you have a class named `.modal`

Here is a working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```